# PHP - Session mismatch, different id and wrong user, hijack risk and a major security risk

Tags: php, ajax, session

Found a major problem on my website. I found tha if I login with user A. it sometimes kinda does log in but actually doesn't. Then I login with user B -> enter the site. I log out and then go manually back to url where login is needed and it somehow goes in with user A. It seems that I have two (maybe could have more) session_id cookies on different tabs or there is a ghost session_id that comes active I don't know. Pulling my hairs here.

Also found that, lets say I have a user dashboard and test page. With a little going back and forth with different credentials. I get this result:
Dashboard echoes user A's id, test echoes user B's id or not id at all. What the heck I am doing wrong with my sessions?
Login is done with AJAX. Login validation is the same on every page.

COMMON FUNCTIONS:

```
    function validateUser($userid) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['usersid'] = $userid;
}

function isLoggedIn() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function logout() {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

LOGIN/DB:
Login page:

```
    session_start();
include 'include_files.php';

if(isLoggedIn()){
    header('Location:loginrequiredpage.php');
    die();
}
```

Login page sends username/password with AJAX to an controller php file that uses db functions as included file. It executes usercheckfunc() which checks user from db and then echoes succes or fail back to ajax.

from db functions - part of user check function

```
//if user found from db and password hash match
validateUser(**ID FROM DATABASE**);
```

Back in login page if ajax gets success message back, JS send user to login required url.
**Here's where mystery sometimes occur** The browser acts like if i just logged in somewhere, but the login page is loaded again. Sometimes I can manually go to login required page via address bar. Sometimes if I logout/idle too long etc. and login with different username/password I get in as a wrong user. Entered as user A, See user B's data OR echo different userids on pages or echo id only on other page.

LOGIN REQUIRED PAGE:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'include_files.php';
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        logout();
        header('Location:login.php');
        die();
    }

echo $_SESSION['usersid'];
```

Test page:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once 'include_files.php';
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        logout();
        header('Location:login.php');
        die();
    }
echo $_SESSION['usersid'];
```

Is there a "best" way to manage sessions? Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you got trouble with session_regenerate_id

Comment: @MarcoMura that's what i thought as well. and why is session id regeneration even needed? imho PHP sessions handle themselves pretty well and you just have to care about creating the session on login and unsetting plus destroying it on logout.

Comment: I agree with Marco, I have had the same problem before with session regenerate id.

Comment: I have been thinking about that but I have no idea what is the most effective way of using it.

Comment: imho -> try use session_start() insted of the regenerating line :) and see if this trouble is resolved or if other will be generated

Comment: There is session_start() in the login controller file that checks user from db.

Comment: I think he meant remove call to session_regenerate_id().

Comment: yes @SidHussain i mean that, OP try your code after commenting/removing that line

Comment: Tried. Same problem occurs. session id sometimes changes after first login (which mysteriously doesn't login) could it be an issue with Javascript redirecting to login required page after successful login?

Comment: It isn't that but the login flow itself. (probably) If the var is setted is setted :) but if it doesn't login than on the first try (when you submit the data) it seems to me that will not use session_start()

Comment: I delete cache and hard reload. Session id is 'abc123' I successfully login and the login page reloads with session id 'def456'. If I now login with different usr/pwd it really goes in and session id is now 'ghi789' - regenerate id part of code is in use.

Comment: After this if I log out. The session id is still 'ghi789'. If I now go manually back to login reguired page. I logs in with different user and session id is now 'prq836';

Comment: Same kind of problems occur if I take off the id regeneration.

Comment: Update for you all. The session id domain changes in the cookie from www.example.com to example.com

Comment: check the URL where you set the session weather it includes www.domain.com OR domain.com  OR weather it include http OR https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got rid of the problem by manually setting session cookie parameters everywhere before session_start is executed. Now the session cookie domain doesn't behave unexpectedly. Sorry, no idea why it did that mysterious changeing before.

This cookie parameters sets it to be valid on whole domain. I guess it's no good in situation where you need different sessions on the same domain (different applications etc.). But for me it was the healing patch I needed.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```